# How do I map a domain name to public ip in azure virtual machine?

Tags: azure

I have created a vm using azure.microsoft.com

I have installed IIS it is working in localhost,

I maped the public ip to iis.

Now I bought a domain from onlydomains.com

How Can I map the domain name to the public Ip ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to onlydomains.com from where you brought the domain, login with your account and open the DNS records of the DNS that you have purchased and want to map it to the Azure VM IP address where your IIS site is running.

Then under that DNS records add A record and provide the public IP of Azure VM. You will be all set then